# How can i access args and kwargs just before celery worker executes a task?

Tags: python, celery

I have a python function that is registered as a celery task like:

```
import celery
@celery.task(base=MyTask)
def my_fn(*args,**kwargs):# dooing stuff
```

I want to check the `args` and `kwargs` are still valid just before the task gets executed.
For this purpose I tried to override `execute` and `run` functions of `Task` class but they are not getting executed as stated in there code and the documentations.(At least that's what I understood!)

[`execute`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/task.py#L772)
[`run`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/task.py#L347)

[a sample use of `run`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes), similer to what I want

This is how I defined my `MyTask` class:

```
from celery import Task
class MyTask(Task):
    def run(self,*args,**kwargs): #does't get called.
    def execute(self,request,*args,**kwargs): #does't get called.
```

What class or function should I be overiding insted?
Is this not possible?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I just Figured out that if you override `__call__` function it works correctly.

The code becomes:

```
from celery import Task
class MyTask(Task):
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        #do stuff
        return super(...)...
```

If there is a better solution I would like to see that though.

Comment: Can you share the code wherein you call the task function? It sounds as though you are calling it locally, not via a remote worker.